# How to change the colour of JTextArea when it is not editable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

When I make JTextArea to display text but not edit it. It will become blue and not visible clearly. How to change the colour of JTextArea when it is not editable?

Comment: which color do you want to change? use setBackground and setForeground methods

Comment: I don't have problem with actual colour but when I make the text area to become not editable it become light blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
JTextArea a = new JTextArea("test");
a.setEnabled(false);
a.setDisabledTextColor(Color.red);
```

Comment: -1, this suggestion was given earlier. No need to repeat the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use

```
public void setDisabledTextColor(Color c)
```

?